# Replacing all values in a column with conditions on a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, memory

I have a decent set of data (37509, 166). I am currently trying to replace 0 in several columns based on a set of conditions. I continued to get a memory error until I changed that value, and now my kernel keeps crashing. My questions is, is there a better way to write this code that avoids memory problems?

```
df = pd.read_csv(".csv")
cols = list(df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).columns)
mask = (df["column1"] <= 0) & (df["column2"] == 0)
df.loc[mask, df[cols]] = np.nan
```

The two columns used for the mask are not included in the cols list and I've tried 1 column at a time. I run into MemoryError every time. I've tried running it through Terality with the same issue.

The error is:

> MemoryError: Unable to allocate 10.5 GiB for an array with shape (37509, 37509) and data type float64.

The following code does not work either (I understand why this code won't work with the copy vs view) for the list of columns or individual column:

```
df[mask][cols].replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)
```

If anyone would be willing to help explain a solution or even just explain the problem, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: `df.loc[mask, df[cols]] = np.nan` should be `df.loc[mask, cols] = np.nan` (the column indexer should just be a list of column names, not a dataframe of those columns)

Comment: Will you please provide a few sample rows from your df? That way, we can generate a larger dataframe from the sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) accepts either booleans or labels:

> Access a group of rows and columns by label(s) or a boolean array.

Currently the column indexer is an entire dataframe `df[cols]`:

```
df.loc[mask, df[cols]] = np.nan
#            ^^^^^^^^
```

Instead of `df[cols]`, use just the `cols` list:

```
df.loc[mask, cols] = np.nan
#            ^^^^
```